# No matter what I do can't flatten this array?

Tags: arrays, php-7.2

Currently looks like this, I have tried almost every conceivable option, can't seem to flatten?

```
[dates] => Array
(
    [0] => 

    2 Jan. 2022


    [1] => 

    5 Jan. 2022


    [2] => 

    12 Jan. 2022


    [3] => 

    19 Jan. 2022


    [4] => 

    26 Jan. 2022

)

Would like it to look normal like this??

`
[flat] => Array
(
    [0] =>2 Jan. 2022
    [1] =>5 Jan. 2022
    [2] =>12 Jan. 2022
    [3] =>19 Jan. 2022
)
```

I have tried functions, loops, trimming, filtering, I'm using PHP7.2 could be bug related?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the way the data was procured, Garbage in garbage out, resolved...